# How do I mix text with cell content to create hyperlink in Excel?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am trying to create many hyperlinks to photos by only copying the hyperlink from one cell into other cells instead of inputting all of them manually. I did quite a bit of reading and trials, but unsuccessfully.

Let's say somewhere on server I have hundreds of photos named in following fashion: "text counter1 (counter2).jpg", e.g. "text 050 (2).jpg".

In auxiliary Excel workbook sheet "FileNames" I have matrix of all these file names created like this "="text" & $a50 & " (" & c$1 & ").jpg)"", which displays "text 050 (2).jpg", where numbers for counter1 are in column A, number for counter2 are in row 1; in this example cell a50 has counter1 value of 050 and cell c1 has counter2 value of 2.

When I try this:

=+HYPERLINK("[file:///\vlp-data2\m1_docs\my name\st\docs\050-079]FileNames!j56",FileNames!J56)

or

=+HYPERLINK("[file:///\vlp-data2\m1_docs\my name\st\docs\050-079]FileNames!j56"&".jpg",FileNames!J56)
(when I don't include the ".jpg" in the file name)

it will open the correct folder, but not the file :o(

Any ideas?
Ideally, I would even like to go without having the file names on the auxiliary sheet, or at least not the whole names, maybe just the combinations of the two counters from column A and row 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me `=HYPERLINK("L:\Dropbox\00- Personal\20- My Programming\VB Excel Code\UDF - User Defined Functions\UDF - GetAddress (Hyperlink as Range).vb","My file")`.

I wonder if something like this doesn't work for you, it's possible that you have a security setting in excel that won't allow you to open files externally.  Mine warned me with:

```
Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern. ... this location my be unsafe.
```

Try your settings  File > Options > Trust Center  .... check External Contentr, File Block settings, trusted locations, and trusted documents.  Make sure something isn't disabled.

Also, try this, it seems like you may have a quotes in the wrong place:

`=+HYPERLINK("[file:///\vlp-data2\m1_docs\my name\st\docs\050-079]" & FileNames!j56 & ".jpg",FileNames!J56)`

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Kerry. Seems like both the square brackets and the quotes were the culprit, it works as I want it to now: = HYPERLINK( "file:///\\vlp-data2\m1_docs\my name\street\docs\050-079\" & FileNames!J56, FileNames!J56 )

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
= HYPERLINK( "file:///\\vlp-data2\m1_docs\my name\pierce st\red tags\050-079\" & FileNames!J56 & ".jpg" , FileNames!J56 )
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the effort, your comment helped me, although not in the form you wrote it. I need to put in the "file:///" else it does not become hyperlink. However i did not need the square brackets, just as you suggested and it worked, with or without the ".jpg". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Slai, would you please replace my name in the hyperlink you posted with something generic, such as "my name"? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. BTW, you can edit/correct answers too so that it helps other people with similar problem better.